# How do you properly implement and verify a perceptron & gradient descent to learn basic Boolean functions in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, machine-learning, neural-network, boolean-logic, perceptron

I'm trying to construct a perceptron unit in Haskell to learn the Boolean And and Or functions, as in Mitchell's book.

I'm pretty sure my gradient descent is correct, but I'm struggling to verify whether it actually learns the alrogithm.  I have three questions, posted in between the code below.

(i) Is my implementation of gradient descent correct?

(ii) If so, is it learing the "best" weights?

(iii) How do you verify the weights are learned correctly.  oor and aand are values when you plug in the boolean pairs into the weights given in the book, but I thought the sgn threshold would apply to these values?  If this was the correct evaluation hypothesis, then Mitchells solution guesses the same and and or function.  Are my learned *and* and  *or* functions (evaluated in ans1, ans2) are incorrect?

```
import System.Random

-- for generating random initial weights
randomList :: Int -> [Double]
randomList seed = randoms (mkStdGen seed) :: [Double]

dotProd x y = foldr (+) 0 $ zipWith (*) x y

gdHelper [] _ del_w _ _ = del_w
gdHelper (x:xs) (t:ts) y@(weight:weights) w nu = gdHelper xs ts del_w w nu
  where del_w = zipWith (+) y (map (*asdf) x)
        asdf = nu * (t - o) 
        o = dotProd w x

gd _  _  _  w _  0 = w
gd xs ts ws w nu n = gd xs ts [0,0,0] w2 nu (n-1)
  where w2 = zipWith (+) w delW
        delW = gdHelper xs ts ws w nu

-- initial weights
w = map (/20) $ take 3 $ randomList 30

trainingData = [([1,1],1),([1,-1],-1),([-1,1],-1),([-1,-1],-1)]
andData = map (1:) (map fst trainingData) 
andOuts = map snd trainingData
orOuts = [1,1,1,-1]

gdand = gd andData andOuts [0,0,0] w 0.02 10000
gdor = gd andData orOuts [0,0,0] w 0.01 10000

ans1 = map (dotProd gdand) andData 
ans2 = map (dotProd gdor) andData 

-- trying to verify this from the book
aand = map (dotProd [-0.8,0.5,0.5]) andData 
oor = map (dotProd [-0.3,0.5,0.5]) andData
```

From Mitchell:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVRAn.png]

Edit: 
Following up, suppose I want to replicate the new Boolean and and Or for data on Boolean valued inputs.  Replace the following code, and the geometric picture remains the same. (w1 = w2 = 1/2, and the intercept is 1/2 its original value).  However, because the data has been both scaled (by 1/2) and translated (by (1/2,1/2)) and my algorithm now learns the wrong function.  `andData = map (1:) [[x,y] | x <- [0,1], y <- [0,1]]

```
andData = map (1:) [[x,y] | x <- [0,1], y <- [0,1]]
andOuts = [0,0,0,1]
orOuts = [0,1,1,1]
oor = map (dotProd [-0.5,1,1]) andData
aand = map (dotProd [-1.5,1,1]) andData
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's a typo in the book: the threshold for OR should be 0.3, not -0.3. After I make that change, I verify that the perceptrons are correct this way:

```
> map signum aand == andOuts
True
> map signum oor == orOuts
True
> map signum ans1 == andOuts
True
> map signum ans2 == orOuts
True
```

The first two verify that the fixed version of the book's weights are suitable; the latter two verify that the weights you learned by gradient descent are suitable.

Comment: Suppose I want to replicate the And and Or for data on Boolean valued inputs. the geometric picture remains the same. (w1 = w2 = 1/2, and the intercept is 1/2 its original value). However, the data has been both scaled (by 1/2) and translated (by (1/2,1/2)) and we now learn the wrong function. (http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/10601_fall2012/hw/hw3_solutions.pdf)`andData = map (1:) [[x,y] | x <- [0,1], y <- [0,1]]

`andData = map (1:) [[x,y] | x <- [0,1], y <- [0,1]]
`andOuts = [0,0,0,1]
`orOuts = [0,1,1,1]
`oor = map (dotProd [-0.5,1,1]) andData
`aand = map (dotProd [-1.5,1,1]) andData